# Cannot adjust GPU fan speed

Tags: graphics-card, fan

I need to modify fan speed settings for a few reasons (mostly loudness and cooling performance), yet all the "typical" approaches that I can find online don't appear to be working.  I have an NVIDIA [GeForce GTX 560, manufactured by Galaxy](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814162084), running on a Windows 7 64-bit desktop (specifically, an HP Z420).  Note that the NVIDIA Control Panel doesn't look to have any fan speed controls in my case.

**First attempt**

The manufacturer's [Xtreme Tuner Plus](http://www.galax.com/en/xtreme-tuner-plus) software alleges to allow fan speed control, but the latest version of the software doesn't support my old GPU and I can't find a way to get to the old version.  The same site says v3.0.0.3 is needed for older GPUs, but has no link.

**Second Attempt**

In [MSI Afterburner](https://www.msi.com/page/afterburner), neither manual adjustment of the fan speed, nor usage of a speed profile have any effect.  The fan speed percentage goes up and down according to what I tell it, but there's no actual change in the fan speed.  This is corroborated in GPU-Z, which shows fan speed as both RPM and a percentage.  As shown below, changing the speed % in MSI Afterburner results in a change to the reported %, but the RPM is the same.  [image: GPU-Z fan speed]

**Third Attempt**

[SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) is even less successful.  Neither the "Fans" tab (shown below) nor the "Fan Control" tab show any fans.  This seems to not be an uncommon problem for this software, though.

**Going Deeper**

Further searching shows:

- [Someone was successful with my card](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/332993-33-control-gtx560) (not sure about manufacturer).
- [Others have reported success](http://www.overclock.net/t/1288381/attention-all-owners-of-galaxy-gtx-560-ti-cards) changing fan speed controls on a similar card using low-level controls

I'm hesitant to attempt something like messing with the video BIOS, especially without more detailed guidance, but cannot find any other options.  Suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure your GPU is suppose to have a fan you can control?  Now all fan controllers are created equal.  If you are not sure of the manufacturer of the card somebody was able to get it to work with, that makes a huge difference, not every GTX 560 is created equal.  Since you don't indicate which version of `Xtreme Tuner Plus` I cannot do research on finding a reputable mirror for you.  It isn't clear the reason you need this capability, might help, if you explain what that reason was.  Additionally, no setting in BIOS, is going to allow you to modify the fan speed on your GPU.

Comment: I was able to find a working [link](http://www.geeks3d.com/20100805/gpu-tool-galaxy-xtreme-tuner-hd-overclocking/) to version 3.0.0 without much effort.  [3.0.0.3 is here](http://www.kfa2.com/XtremeTunerHD_v303.zip)

Comment: Can you get access to the connector on the GPU where the fan gets its power?  Maybe you could stick a manual fan speed controller [like this](https://www.neweggbusiness.com/product/product.aspx?item=9siv0vz5uh9728) in between the fan and the GPU.

Comment: @Ramhound I found that link to 3.0.0.3 before, it doesn't work.  I have no idea what I can/cannot do with my fan, and I'll update the post with more details.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh and it's the video BIOS, not the computer BIOS.